# Can we specify no of cycles in sequences in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I started to create a sequence in Oracle. While going through the oracle documentation I got this prototype

```
Create Sequence SeqTest5
Start With 0
Increment by 1
Min value 0
Maxvalue 8
NoCycle    --I got to know we can give this as 'Cycle' which will again
           -- Repeat the loop. But my doubt is why cannot we specify  number of 
           -- Loops. Such as Cycle 20             
NoCache    --I got to know we can give certain buffer lenght via cache
```

Can you Please explain me why cannot we declare it as I have tried it and got this error

```
1  create sequence seqtest4
2  cache 30,
3* cycle 20,
SQL> /
cache 30,
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

For Example:-

```
TNUM
     0
     1
     4
     2
     3
     5
     6
     7
     8
```

This 0-8 should write 10 times and stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the number of cycles; just whether or not you want to cycle. The `CREATE SEQUENCE` syntax is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm).

There are a few problems with your `CREATE SEQUENCE` above:

- The commas - they don't belong; just get rid of them.
- Specifying `CYCLE 20` - you can specify `CYCLE` or `NOCYCLE` only. The default is `NOCYCLE`.
- If you specify `CYCLE` you must also specify a `MAXVALUE`.

---

**Addendum**: Question updated with actual requirement, which is to count 1-8 ten times. Here's how to do it without sequences; it's based on an often-used Oracle trick for generating number sequences:

```
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8
```

The statement above will output the numbers 1 through 8, in order. To repeat it ten times you need to do another "1 through 10" counter, then cross join it to the "1 through 8", then make sure it orders correctly. This complicates thing a bit, which can be seen in the final answer:

```
SELECT SeqCounter FROM (
  SELECT SeqCounter, CycleCounter FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL AS SeqCounter FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8)
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT LEVEL AS CycleCounter FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
) ORDER BY CycleCounter, SeqCounter
```

The statement above will give the output requested in the question.

Comment: Thank you @ED Gibbs can you tell me why I cannot do it. And Is there any alternative way ?

Comment: I'm not sure of the "why" - Oracle doesn't go into it so I'd just be guessing. I do know this is the first time I've heard of a requirement to cycle a specific number of times. Sequences are mostly used for PK's and those don't cycle. I've done cycling sequences before but very few. I don't know of any alternative approaches using DDL. You'd have to code this by hand, and I'm afraid I can't help you with that as I'm headed out of town for the next few days. **Note:** I just saw your updated question and you can do that without sequences; I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK, the updated answer is in place now. Just so you know, I'm headed out for a few hours so if you have any questions I'll try to get to them when I return.

Comment: Thank You @Ed Gibbs Sonice of you ! will complete what you said to night it self! Thank you

Comment: Hello @Ed Gibbs Please accept my Linkedin req. my name is CHAITANAYA PENUBARTHY  I have few confusions on the above query this is working fine but still I cannot get the usage of the     SELECT statment

Comment: Hi @user2255026 - the best way to understand is run each of the subqueries separately, starting from the innermost and working out. `SELECT LEVEL AS SeqCounter FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8` gives you the numbers 1-8. `SELECT LEVEL AS CycleCounter FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10` gives you the numbers 1-10. `SELECT SeqCounter, CycleCounter FROM ( the inner queries... )` cross joins the two: every row from the first is matched with every row from the second. Finally, the very outer query (a) orders the results and (b) hides the `CycleCounter`.

Comment: ok Thanks for the explanation got a good view on from clause sub queries !

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be best handled with a modulo function?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqtest5 START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 80 NOCYCLE;

SELECT mod(seqtest5.nextval, 9) from dual;

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

ORA-08004: sequence SEQTEST5.NEXTVAL exceeds MAXVALUE and cannot be instantiated
```